# query with date_part, how to get sub_query to play along?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
Select  date_part('Day', t.timestamp) as day_of_month, 
        Count(id) total, 
        (
            Select  Count(id) 
            From    the_table 
            Where   text_string_column Like '%keyword%'
        ) 
From    the_table   t 
Group By date_part('Day', t.timestamp) 
Order By date_part('Day', t.timestamp) Desc
```

returns

```
            count   day_of_month    total
            16445   21              447851
            16445   20              552149
```

I need the count to be relevant to the day returned (or any other date_part type)

thanks for your time!

Comment: does your table have a primary key column?  If so you could change count(*) to count(id)

Comment: good point, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, you only need to hit the table once and use `SUM` combined with `CASE` to get your "conditional count", rather than using a subquery, which causes a second scan of the same table.

For example, try this:

```
Select  date_part('Day', t.timestamp) as day_of_month, 
    Count(id) total, 
    sum(case when text_string_column Like '%keyword%' then 1 else 0 end)
From    the_table   t 
Group By date_part('Day', t.timestamp) 
Order By date_part('Day', t.timestamp) Desc
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. This technique is useful in many, many situations.  If it worked, would you mind marking it as the answer? :)